# найти проблему в коде по склейке файлов

Tags: python

У меня есть код он склеивает все файлы в папке в один

```
DIRECTORY = 'C:/Users/path/'
def unite():
    a = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)
    b = len(a)
    fout = open(DIRECTORY + "out.csv", mode='a')
    for line in open(DIRECTORY + a[0]):
        fout.write(line)
    for num in range(1, b):
        f = open(DIRECTORY + a[num])
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            fout.write(line)
    fout.close()
    print('FileUnite!')
unite()
```

Но иногда при выполнении программы файл out.csv начинает склеивать сам себя по много раз.
Можно как то сделать игнорирование файла out.csv? Или есть какое-то другое решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DIRECTORY = 'C:/Users/path/'
def unite():
    a = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)
    a.remove('out.csv')
    b = len(a)
    fout = open(DIRECTORY + "out.csv", mode='a')
    for line in open(DIRECTORY + a[0]):
        fout.write(line)
    for num in range(1, b):
        f = open(DIRECTORY + a[num])
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            fout.write(line)
    fout.close()
    print('FileUnite!')
unite()
```